# After setting backIndicatorImage, how to reuse the system's back icon?

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote the following code and set a custom back button icon:

```swift
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()

navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = image
navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = image
```

It works, which is good.

But now in another controller, I want to reuse the system’s back button icon.

I have tried the following in the new controller:

1. Set `backIndicatorImage` and `backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage` to nil.
2. `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil`

But this doesn't work.

My application needs to support iOS 10, so I cannot use SF Symbol.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem, and still set `backIndicatorImage` and `backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage` to `nil`.

But I used to set up on the current controller, the correct way should be set up on the **upper controller**.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the baseviewcontroller for your vc and in the class can create the back button like this:

```
   class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

   let backButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.setTitle("P", for: .normal)
    btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "app", size: 26)!
    btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)
    btn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -7, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    
    return btn
}()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonTouchUpInside), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers, viewControllers.count > 1 {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
    } else {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = []
    }
}

@objc func backButtonTouchUpInside() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
}
```

and use like that

```
class ViewController: BaseViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(back), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)

}
@objc func back(index : Int) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
}
```